# jq: avoid empty arrays mapped field

Tags: jq

Here my jq script:

```
def pick_nationality:
  select(.NACIONALITAT) |
  {nation: {country: .NACIONALITAT, code: "some code"} };

def pick_surname: 
  select(.SURNAME) |
  {name: {surname: .SURNAME, code: "some code"} };

def pick_extension:
  { use: "official", extension: [pick_nationality, pick_surname] };

map(pick_extension)
```

Input json is like:

```json
{
  "SURNAME": "surname1"
}
{
  "NACIONALITAT": "nacionalitat1"
}
```

However, sometimes any input objects don't contain any look up field:

```json
{
  "field1": "value1"
}
{
  "field2": "value2"
}
```

Above script returns:

```json
[
  {
    "use": "official",
    "extension": []
  },
  {
    "use": "official",
    "extension": []
  }
]
```

I'd like `extension` doesn't appear:

```json
[
  {
    "use": "official"
  },
  {
    "use": "official"
  }
]
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply add

```
| del(..|select(. == []))
```

as a trailing to your script in order to remove all such empty arrays

<kbd>[Demo](https://jqplay.org/s/j8KVWtctGn)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

extend your function `pick_extension` for the desired output:

```
def pick_extension:
  [pick_nationality, pick_surname] as $extension
  | { use: "official" }
  | if $extension | length > 0 then . + {extension: $extension} else . end;
```

If no extension could be picked, the empty array will no longer be added to the json object this way.